# Can I do a binary build that works for M1 / M2 even if I have an older (non-M1) Mac Book Pro?

Tags: xcode, apple-silicon, rosetta

I distribute a software for Windows and Mac (with an installer PKG/DMG, without any Store), 99% of the code is crossplatform and I spend 99.9% of the development time on Windows. I have fewer experience on Mac build tools, and I only use a Mac Book Pro 2 or 3 times per year to build and release updates.

**Question: in XCode, can I build a release binary for Mac, including the target M1/M2 users (so that M1 users of my software don't have to deal with [Rosetta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosetta_(software))), from my non-M1 Mac Book Pro?**

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can.

> You can build a universal binary on either an Apple silicon or Intel-based Mac computer, but you cannot debug the arm64 slice of your binary on an Intel-based Mac computer. It’s possible to debug both slices of a universal binary on Apple silicon, but you must run the x86_64 slice under Rosetta translation.

From: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apple-silicon/building-a-universal-macos-binary

Full instructions also on the same page.